# how to insert 15 digit number into access database through vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i have this query-

```
"insert into FROM_MASTER values('" & n & "'," & TextBox2.Text & ",'" & _
TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & u & "," & k & "," & id & ")"
```

and following are the values-

```
"insert into FROM_MASTER values('22/02/2013',9999999999999,'ok','ok',9999999999999,1,1)"
```

it is giving datatype mismatch exeception.and i am inserting date as string .so, no matter with date.only matter is that long number.plz help me out

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Let's see the structure of the table.

Comment: As @Paul says, you will need the right data type.

Comment: Without knowing the datatype of every column in the FROM_MASTER table is anyone guess to find this error. Probably the second and fifth columns are of type long integer and cannot receive the value 9999999999999. You need a decimal column for that.

Comment: @Steve in Access, a double would be best.

Comment: If you don't need to do any calculations with those numbers in the database try changing the column data type to text and storing them as strings also.

Comment: no i want to do operations with it

Answer (score 1):

The largest number Microsoft Access Data Types is LONG (4byte) , your number (9999999999999) is larger than it is , to solve the problem use string.